# Setting value of name attribute breaks after setAttribute()

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to create a name attribute and set a value to it using resultset methods, but it breaks after `request.setAttribute(..)`.

Go out of the first if else structure, but doesn't proceed the forwarding or return statement.

If I use `rs.next()` as the value of the name it works perfectly well, so I'm pretty sure the way I am using `rs.getString` is wrong. I checked documentation and cannot find my mistake.

```
String sql = "select * from students where id="+ request.getParameter("st_id");
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(sql);

if (rs.wasNull()) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_fail.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return; 
}else{
    request.setAttribute("name", rs.getString("name"));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_action.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `rs.next()`. Because when you received the ResultSet cursor is pointing to the place before the first row of the resultset. So you must call `next()` method and then get the results
In java API it says

```
boolean next() throws SQLException

Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
```

[Read documentation on ResultSet.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())

So you can code as follows

```
String sql = "select * from students where id="+ request.getParameter("st_id");
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(sql);

if(rs.next()){
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_fail.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        request.setAttribute("name", rs.getString("name"));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_action.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to change your query and provide column names in that like this:

```
String sql = "select name, col1 from students where id="+ request.getParameter("st_id");
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

and then you  can use the rs.getstring like this:

```
if(rs.next())
{
if (rs.wasNull()) 
{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_fail.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return;
}
else
{
    request.setAttribute("name", rs.getString(1));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_action.jsp").forward(request, response);
    return;
}
}
```

Comment: it doesn't give an error, i debugged it, goes out of the nested if and keep working.

it doesn't proceed request.getRequestDispatcher(..) and return(..)

Answer (score 0):

Please print the column names here.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

// The column count starts from 1
for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
  String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
   System.out.println(name);
}
```

Try changing code as below

```
String sql = "select * from students where id="+ request.getParameter("st_id");
            ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            if (rs.wasNull()) {
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_fail.jsp").forward(request, response);
                return; 
            }else{
              while (resultSet.next()) {
                request.setAttribute("name", rs.getString("name"));
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/login_action.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
            return; 
            }
```